# Delimiters included /not included in the same regular expression line

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is a code with a regular expression:

```
string StringX= TextBoxY.Text;

string[] splicharX = Regex.Split(StringX, @"\s(today.+|but|)\s");
```

Example text:

Today they are really tired but tomorow they will go back to work.

```
I want this output: Today they are really tired
```

another example(with this regular expression: @"\s(today.+|but|.+back)\s"):

Today they are really tired but tomorow they will go back to work.

```
I want this output: Today they are really tired 
                    tomorow they will go back
```

So in these examples I want delimiters to be included like today.+ and .+back  and want |but| to be not included in the pattern how to realize this regular expression in the same line to work well on a multiline text?

Comment: If you use `Split()` it won't include the delimiters. You have to use the method `Match()` instead. You've already asked similar question like two days ago : you seem not to understand how to use **Split** and **Match**. I suggest you to read the documentation of the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` methods.

Comment: You can simply use this regex: `@"but|to work"`.

Comment: Or you use `string.Split` like this: `StringX.Split(new string[]{"but", "to work"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` to get rid of the extra empty string.

Comment: I use these words as a delimiter but|today|back  and I want some delimiters to keep(today|back) but others deleted(but) in a sentence...

Comment: I see in this comment `I am using but as a delimiter which must be excluded from the pattern and using today which is must be included in the patter on the left side and the other word back which must be included but on the right side` but the part in the example data `tomorow they will go back` does not start with `Today` You can not have discontinued matches  in a single match.

Comment: what is the solution then? I use or | as a multiple match, want to keep some delimiters and not keep other delimiters with pattern...

Comment: Why don't you match `\b[Tt]oday\b.*?\bback\b` and then split on *but* ? See https://regex101.com/r/4qLY6E/1

Answer (score 0):

Try to **match** (and not split) with this regex : `^(.+)\sbut\s(.+back)\s.+$` => https://regex101.com/r/XiaLfT/3

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(.+)\sbut\s(.+back)\s.+$";
        string input = @"Today they are really tired but tomorow they will go back to work.";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline| RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
        
        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, options);
        foreach(Group g in m.Groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", g.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: in my example I do not want delimiter "but" included and in the same time I want "today" and "back" included... this code does not excludes "but" how I showed in  my example and on the right side word "back" must be ended as in my example... this code is not the right solution....

Comment: so in my example I am using three words: but; today; back      -> I am using but as a delimiter which must be excluded from the pattern and using today which is must be included in the patter on the left side and the other word back which must be included but on the right side....

Comment: What ? Have you seen the results in the regex tool ? Have you tried to execute the example code in a console application in Visual Studio ? You have to use `Match()` you'll get the result you mentionned in your post. You insist to use `Split()` and I am telling you it won't work !

Comment: How come I get the right results ?

Comment: I have seen it in the regex tool and the string "but" is included in the sentence which shouldn`t be... and also part of the sentence "to work" should be excluded too but it isn`t.....

Comment: The right results are in the `m.Groups[1]` and `m.Groups[2]`. Explore them by adding a spy on the `m.Groups` property in Visual Studio. The console application displays only what matched and not what was captured in groups.