# Keep some delimiters and others not with pattern with Regex split

Tags: python, .net, regex

I have a code like this:

```
string splitttt ="This week rained all day long but next day will be a sunny day if the news are correct"

string[] splitttt = Regex.Split(StringX, @"\s(week|if|)\s");
```

I get this output: `rained all day long but next day will be a sunny day` (in this case delimiters are not included in the pattern)  This is works fine but in the next case I have a problem:

I want a case where some delimiters are included and others not:
for example using three delimiters: `week|if|next`   I want to keep delimiters |week| and |if| and I do not want to keep delimiter |next| but still want it to work as a delimiter:

for example: "This week rained all day long but next day will be a sunny day if the news are correct"

I want a regular expression like this `@"\s(week.+|.+if|next)\s"`

This should be the output:

```
week rained all day long but 

day will be a sunny day if
```

so in this case:

week.+  - splits the text but remains in the beginning of the matched pattern
next    - splits the text but do not remain in the returned pattern
.+if     - splits the text but remains in the end of the matched pattern

I am struggling almost five days to find a solution for it. Tried many regular expression combinations and didn`t find a working solution.
Exactly what regular expression should use to achieve this thing??

Comment: Do you mean like match `\bweek\b.*?\bnext\b.*?\bif\b` and then split on `next`? https://regex101.com/r/LvlbJW/1

Comment: There is a similar question here that you posted earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74520547/delimiters-included-not-included-in-the-same-regular-expression-line

Comment: If I put (week.+next) together it works fine, week is included in pattern and next not in the same time but the problem is that I want to use many other delimiters combined with week.+ , somehow I should use match and split simultaniasly

Answer (score 0):

You can include matched text in your output by defining the delimiters with lookaround:

```
import re

string = "This week rained all day long but next day will be a sunny day if the news are correct"

pattern = r" (?=week)|(?<=if) | next "

split = re.split(pattern, string)

for word in split:
    print(word)
```

This way, the word "week" isn't part of the delimiter itself; it simply constrains the pattern to match spaces that are followed by "week".